# error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: macos, openssl

I am having and old Macbook running Osx Lion 10.7.5 which is the highest upgrade that it supports.
On running git clone I get this error.

```
Veers-Macbook:~ Veer$ git clone https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started.git
Cloning into 'python-getting-started'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started.git/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Based on other similar questions, my system details are as follows:

```
Veers-Macbook:~ Veer$ which git
/usr/local/git/bin/git

Veers-Macbook:~ Veer$ git --version
git version 2.3.5

Veers-Macbook:~ Veer$ git config http.sslVersion
tlsv1.2
```

I ran these two commands

```
    git config --global --unset http.sslVersion
    git config --global --add http.sslVersion tlsv1.2
```

To verify I ran the config file

```
 Veers-Macbook:~ Veer$ git config --global --list
 user.name=Gurupratap Matharu
 user.email=gurupratap.matharu@gmail.com
 credential.helper=osxkeychain
 core.excludesfile=/Users/admin/.gitignore
 mergetool.sublime.cmd=subl -w $MERGED
 mergetool.sublime.trustexitcode=false
 merge.tool=sublime
 alias.gui=!sh -c '/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-gui'
 http.sslversion=tlsv1.2
```

Looks like the config file has the http tlsv1.2 but the error still persists.

could you guide how can I fix this. My only aim is to use github via the command line.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by old encryption on lion, which the internet has declared as deprecated ( for example, https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/ )

For one solution, you can try tigerbrew https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew

For a different experimental solution, I have made my own very simple package here: http://try.gitea.io/donbright/lm which will bootstrap curl and git on a Lion machine if you have Xcode + Xcode command line tools already installed. However your complicated git config will maybe not work with it, you might have to wipe the config clean.